# Which RNG is used in Scratch?

Tags: mit-scratch

Which random number generator is used in Scratch 1.4 and where can I find its implementaion in the source code? If it is just libc's `random()`, please point me to the spot where it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scratch 1.x is written in Squeak Smalltalk. You can get the source code from within Scratch by following [these instructions](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Shift-Click-R#Accessing_the_System_Browser).

The `pick random () to ()` block is defined in Scratch-Objects -> ScriptableScratchMorph (instance) -> other ops -> `randomFrom:to:`. The basic essential code there is

```
t5 _ RandomGen next * (t4 - t3) + t3.
```

Now, what is `RandomGen`? It turns out that it's defined in Scratch (in the class initialization) as just being a copy of Squeak's `Random`.

According to [the Squeak wiki](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/5744):

> The random-number-generator is a Park-Miller generator, it is implemented in the class Random.

Scratch also calls for a random number in some [list blocks](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/List_Blocks), where you can do something with "any" list item. This is implemented in `list ops -> lineNum:forList:`.